# TinkerCAD switch seems to be not working (always closed)

Tags: switch, simulator

I am using TinkerCAD to simulate the functionality of a slide switch. Please comment if you think this question is off-topic.

```
/*
  LiquidCrystal Library - Hello World

 Demonstrates the use a 16x2 LCD display.  The LiquidCrystal
 library works with all LCD displays that are compatible with the
 Hitachi HD44780 driver. There are many of them out there, and you
 can usually tell them by the 16-pin interface.

 This sketch prints "Hello World!" to the LCD
 and shows the time.

  The circuit:
 * LCD RS pin to digital pin 12
 * LCD Enable pin to digital pin 11
 * LCD D4 pin to digital pin 5
 * LCD D5 pin to digital pin 4
 * LCD D6 pin to digital pin 3
 * LCD D7 pin to digital pin 2
 * LCD R/W pin to ground
 * LCD VSS pin to ground
 * LCD VCC pin to 5V
 * 10K resistor:
 * ends to +5V and ground
 * wiper to LCD VO pin (pin 3)

 Library originally added 18 Apr 2008
 by David A. Mellis
 library modified 5 Jul 2009
 by Limor Fried (http://www.ladyada.net)
 example added 9 Jul 2009
 by Tom Igoe
 modified 22 Nov 2010
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystal
 */
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const byte pin8 = 8;

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // open the serial port at 9600 bps:      
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Welcome.");  
}

void loop() {
  byte val = digitalRead(pin8);
  Serial.println(val);
  if(val == HIGH)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Switch on right.");
  }
  else
  {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Switch on left.");
  }  
}
```

The serial monitor and the output of the LCD screen are showing the slide switch to always be on the right side (not creating an open circuit when the switch is on the left side). 
[image]
As seen in the picture, the switch is on the left. And the code, I think, is correct. So it should display, "Switch on left." This is because `pin8` is low (not connected to 3.3V).

So I'm very confused. The switch appears to be shorting all three rails to which it's connected. When the switch is removed, that part becomes open; `pin8` is low.

Comment: General idea not to leave your pin floating.
If I were you I would use a pull-down resistor (10K) from pin8 to GND.

Comment: Is there a way to make your circuit and code public? so we can try it?

Answer (score -1):

As  Sener said, "use a pull-down resistor (10K) from pin8 to GND."

[image]

And in case anyone notices, yes, I'm aware of `clear()`.

---

TinkerCAD must be assuming a [floating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground) input reads high instead of an intrinsically floating ground. The most simple solution is adding `pinMode(pin8, INPUT_PULLUP);` to the setup() function. Then, tie the opposite (than with a resistor) side of the switch to ground: [Modified circuit TinkerCAD simulation](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/bupjVk1XiYk). 
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is also way to do but then you have to invert the switch function. Means, instead of going 3.3V it should be GND this time.